# Can't figure out a compilation error for simple Java app

Tags: java

This is the error I am getting: 
**Error: The type Customer must implement the inherited abstract method java.lang.Comparable.compareTo(Customer)**

I'm comparing it to some lab work that I did and it looks exactly the same, yet that compiled just fine. I'm not sure what's going on here.

Here is the code segment in question which, incidentally, was written by my professor:

```
class Customer implements Comparable<Customer>
{
 String name;
 double purchase;
 double rebate;

public Customer(String n, double p, double r)
{ name=n;
  purchase=p;
  rebate=r;
 } //end Constructor

 public Customer(String n)
 { 
  name=n;
 } //end Constructor

 public String toString()
 {
  return String.format("%-20s%10.2f%10.2f", name, purchase, rebate);
 }

 /*
  Here, define the method comparedTo of the Comparable
  interface so that an array of Customer objects can
  be sorted by customer name
 */
 public int comparedTo(Customer a)
{
return this.name.compareTo(a.name);
}   //end comparedTo

} //end class Customer
```

Oh, and here are the inclusions the professor included:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Lish: Welcome to Code Review.  This site is for reviewing working code, not for solving compilation problems.  Migrating this to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

`comparedTo` should be `compareTo`.

The error says it all. ;p

Comment: Agh. I must not be able to read because I totally didn't make that connection. I was just going by what the professor said to do in the problem statement. It did seem a little odd that we were working with 'compareTo()' and we suddenly switched to 'comparedTo()', though.

Answer (score 0):

As Steven correctly pointed out, the name of the method you were attempting to implement was misspelled. A great way to catch errors like that is the `@Override` annotation, like this:

```
@Override
public int comparedTo(Customer a)
```

This tells the compiler that you intended comparedTo() to override a method declared in a parent class. When the compiler doesn't find a comparedTo() method to override, it will tell you. As of Java 1.6, `@Override` can also be used on methods declared in interfaces.

Comment: Oh, cool. I'll keep that in mind for next time. I had no idea that was possible.